# TouchableOpacity with parent PanResponder

Tags: react-native, gestures

I have a parent `PanResponder` with a child TouchableOpacity.
What happens is that the `TouchableOpacity` doesn't respond to clicks because the `PanResponder` takes the click.
I have tried to follow this guide but no success:
http://browniefed.com/blog/react-native-maintain-touchable-items-with-a-parent-panresponder/

this is my code:

```
this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
            onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => false,
            onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: () => true,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => {
                return gestureState.dx != 0 && gestureState.dy != 0;
            },
            onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
                let isFirst = gestureState.y0 > 164 ? false : true;
                this.setState({animObj: isFirst, isUsingCurtain: true});
            },
            onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {

                //let Y = this.state.animObj ? gestureState.moveY - this.state.currentHeaderHeight  : gestureState.moveY - this.state.currentHeaderHeight ;// - this.state.currentHeaderHeight;
                let Y = gestureState.moveY - this.state.currentHeaderHeight + 20
                if (Y < 0) {
                    return false
                }
                this.state.animCurtain.setValue(Y);
                gestureState.moveY > height / 2 ? this.setState({curtainOnMiddle: true}) : this.setState({curtainOnMiddle: false})
            },
            onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => true,
            onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
                if (((height / 2) > gestureState.moveY)) {//slide back up1
                    this._CurtainAnimation(0, false);
                } else {//slide to bottom
                    let val = height - calcSize(180);
                    this._CurtainAnimation(val, true);
                }
            },
            onPanResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => {
            },
            onPanResponderStart: (e, gestureState) => {
            },
        });
```

and this is my View :

```
<Animated.View
            style={[styles.bottomHPHeader, TopArroOpacity ? {opacity: TopArroOpacity} : ""]} {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._animateAutoCurtain()}>
                {this.state.curtainOnMiddle ?
                    <AIIcon image={require('../../../../assets/images/homepage/close_drawer_arrow.png')}
                            boxSize={30}/>
                    : <AIIcon image={require('../../../../assets/images/homepage/open_drawer_arrow.png')}
                              boxSize={30}/>}
            </TouchableOpacity></Animated.View>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The solution for my case was to modify `onMoveShouldSetPanResponder`

```
onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
    //return true if user is swiping, return false if it's a single click
                return !(gestureState.dx === 0 && gestureState.dy === 0)                  
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Perfect! I just needed to adjust because of the sensitivity.

```
onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
      const { dx, dy } = gestureState
      return dx > 2 || dx < -2 || dy > 2 || dy < -2
}
```

Comment: If I could give you more votes, I would. Thank you! I have fat fingers and couldn't figure out how to adjust for sensitivity. This is perfect

Comment: This one works fine. But instead of checking for negative, I just instead Math.abs: `return Math.abs(gestureState.dx) > 2 || Math.abs(gestureState.dy) > 2;`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same exact issue. The solution was a combination of the above solutions. Had to add a condition for both the onMoveShouldSetPanResponder and onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture. Here is what I did.

```js
 onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (_, gestureState) => {
    const { dx, dy } = gestureState
    return (dx > 2 || dx < -2 || dy > 2 || dy < -2)
  },
  
onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (_, gestureState) => {
    const { dx, dy } = gestureState
    return (dx > 2 || dx < -2 || dy > 2 || dy < -2)
  },
```

Comment: You freaking life saver ! I struggled for hours trying to understand why not a single touchable was working in an AnimatedView that use a PanResponder.

It should be written somewhere that nothing inside a panResponder can emmit it's touchable event, unless the PanResponder is "inactive"

Comment: Happy to help Topsy! You could also try importing `TouchableOpacity` from `'react-native-gesture-handler'`. This may also behave better / fix instances like this.

Answer (score 6):

```js
this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => false,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems a slightly different situation works for everyone... here is the combination of `PanResponder.create` properties which worked for me (I was trying to allow taps through to child elements, but capture moves with the PanResponder:

```
onStartShouldSetPanResponder:        ( e, state ) => false,
onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: ( e, state ) => false,
onMoveShouldSetPanResponder:         ( e, state ) => true,
onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture:  ( e, state ) => true,
```

I hope this helps someone else and it doesn't somehow come back to haunt me!

Answer (score 1):

I came up to the similar problem but for me having a container view containing the pan view inside while having the button on absolute position & keeping it above pan view did help. It could not fit for everyone but for the cases (like mine) where button can be absolutely positioned, it works.

Here's a sample code of a component that has the pan view and button.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Animated,
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  PanResponder,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";


export class ToolRuler extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      moveX: 0,
      moveY: 0
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => false,
      onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: () => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // anything
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        this.setState({
          moveX: gestureState.moveX,
          moveY: gestureState.moveY
        });
      },
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
        this.setState({
          moveX: gestureState.moveX,
          moveY: gestureState.moveY
        });
      },
      onPanResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => {},
      onPanResponderStart: (e, gestureState) => {}
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          position: "relative",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
      >
        <Animated.View
          {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
          style={{ flex: 1, width: "100%", backgroundColor: "#ccc" }}
        >
          <Text style={{ marginTop: 200, textAlign: "center" }}>
            x: {this.state.moveX}, y: {this.state.moveY}
          </Text>
        </Animated.View>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            position: "absolute"
          }}
          onPress={() => alert("I am tapped!")}
        >
          <Text>Click Me</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution for Android. All others return `false`

```
onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, { dx, dy }) => dx !== 0 || dy !== 0,
```

Answer (score 0):

The above fixes did not work for me but the following did -

set `onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture` to `false` in `PanResponder.create`

Below is my panResponder code

```
 const panResponder = React.useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      // We need this code to listen for onPress vs pan events
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => false,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {
        if (gestureState.dy > 0) {
          Animated.event([null, { dy: pan.y }], { useNativeDriver: false })(
            e,
            gestureState,
          );
        }
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // If pulled down far enough, dismiss modal
        if (gestureState.dy > SWIPE_DISTANCE) onCancel();
        else {
          // If not dismissed slide back to standard height
          Animated.spring(pan, {
            toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 },
            useNativeDriver: false,
          }).start();
        }
      },
      onShouldBlockNativeResponder: () => true,
    }),
  ).current;
```