# React Native - Touchable Opacity inside Animated.View is firing event of background list view

Tags: react-native

I Have a list with scroll view, I am trying to add filter options for it. When click on a filter icon, an overlay with `position:absolute` will be displayed inside a Animated.View. I have Buttons inside overlay View with `TouchableOpacity`

Filter.js

```
    export default class FilterFade extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          visible: props.visible,
        };
    };

    componentWillMount() {
      this._visibility = new Animated.Value(this.props.visible ? 1 : 0);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

        if (nextProps.visible) {
          this.setState({ visible: true });
        }
        Animated.timing(this._visibility, {
          toValue: nextProps.visible ? 1 : 0,
          duration: 300,
        }).start(() => {
          this.setState({ visible: nextProps.visible });
        });
    }

    render() {
      const { visible, style, children, ...rest } = this.props;

      const containerStyle = {
        opacity: this._visibility.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [0, 1],
        }),
        transform: [
          {
            scale: this._visibility.interpolate({
              inputRange: [0, 1],
              outputRange: [1.1, 1],
            }),
          },
        ],
      };

      const combinedStyle = [containerStyle, style];
      return (
        <Animated.View style={combinedStyle} {...rest}>
          {children}
        </Animated.View>
      );
    }
  }
```

View.js

```
<FilterFade visible={this.state.isFilterVisible}>
          <View style={styles.filterView}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.getFilteedStories}>
                <Text style={styles.filterOption}> My Stories </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.getFilteedStories}>
              <Text style={styles.filterOption}> All Stories </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
 </FilterFade>
```

Styles

```
 filterView :{
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      right: 5,
      backgroundColor: #CCC,
      width: 150,
      paddingTop: 15,
      paddingBottom: 15,
      zIndex: 999,
    },
    filterOption: {
      color: "#FFF",
      fontSize: 15

    }
```

Now, When I click on TouchableOpacity Text in Filter, the click event is triggered in Listview which is behind the FadeView.

Can Some one please let me know on how to add press event inside a Animated absolute view.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: @Cris69 No, I removed Fade animation from my application. please let me know if you found anything related to it, Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Use TouchableOpacity from 'react-native-gesture-handler' instead of from 'react-native'.

import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

Follow this post [Cannot click TouchableOpacity in animated.view using React native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45728689/cannot-click-touchableopacity-in-animated-view-using-react-native)